# Replace all files in a folder with empty text file named with the replaced files

Tags: batch-file, replace, rename

I have a bunch of folders and inside each of those folders are multiple files (all mkv files if that matters)

What I would like to do is run through each of the folders and replace every mkv file within the folder with an empty text file named after the deleted mkv file.

The mkv files all have different names. Can this be done with a batch file and `copy /b NUL EmptyFile.txt` somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply loop through the directories and use the variable expansion to get the name, create the text file and then delete the `.mkv` file:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s *.mkv') do break>"%%~dpni.txt" && del /Q /S "%%~i"
```

This will simply assign each file name to the metavariable `%%i` then expand to the drive, path and name `%%~dpni` and add an extension, in your case you wanted `.txt` using `break` to create an empty file.

Please first test this in a test folder before you run it on your actual files.

Comment: This worked flawlessly, I placed it in the parent directory of the subfolders. Did exactly what it was supposed to do and now I have just empty text files as reference markers instead of having to keep 50GB of mkv files around lol.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN (`DIR /A:d /B "C:\ParentFolder"`) DO (
    FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%B IN (`DIR /B "C:\ParentFolder\%%A"`) DO (
        DEL /Q /F "C:\ParentFolder\%%A\%%B" > NUL 2>&1
        ECHO. > "C:\ParentFolder\%%A\%%~nB.txt"
    )
)
```

This will search for all the folders within `C:\ParentFolder`, and then fetch all files within the subfolders, and then delete any found files and `echo` (print) a blank line to a txt file with the same name as the original file.

`DIR` lists all files within a given folder, `/B` specifies that only bare file names and extensions are to be output. `/A:d` specifies to list directories (folders) only.

`DEL` deletes files, `/Q` specifies quietly with no confirmation, `/F` forces deletion of read only files (Not really necessary in this case but whatever)

`ECHO.` echoes (prints) a blank line, `>` outputs it to the provided file (It will create the file if it doesn't exist). `%%~nB` specifies only the name of the file, excluding the extension.

If you are not using this in a script, the following code works as a one-liner: `` FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %A IN (`DIR /A:d /B "C:\ParentFolder"`) DO ( FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %B IN (`DIR /B "C:\ParentFolder\%A"`) DO DEL /Q /F "C:\ParentFolder\%A\%B">NUL 2>&1 & ECHO. > "C:\ParentFolder\%A\%~nB.txt" ) ``

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful especially with the descriptions of what each command is doing.
How could I change it to work when it's already inside /ParentFolder?

My folder structure is 
T:/Shows/TVShow/Season1
T:/Shows/TVShow/Season2 
etc,
The batch file would be running from the "T:/Shows/TVShow/" folder and running through all of the season folders.

Comment: so I replaced the path with my path, "F:\TV Shows\Show1" and when I run the file from the "F:\TV Shows\Show1" folder, nothing happens.

"Show1" is the directory that contains multiple other directories and the files I want to replace